# BLE does not connect after disconnect with bonded devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

hi my question is simple as lot of people asked and face this issue:

I connect to one BLE Peripheral device, Bond created with that device. When my device (Mobile) get disconnected from gatt server. Again I am unable to connect to the gatt server, The connection request gives gat server Error 133.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you disconnecting, can you please add some code and logs

Comment: public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothGattServer not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }

Comment: After disconnect I am also calling close(), Problem is in Android 5.1, 4.4.4, 5.1.0, 6.0.1 is working fine, But Not working 6.0, and 5.0,5.2 etc. Any Help??